# How to add pre-build step in qmake/qtcreator?

Tags: version-control, qmake, prebuild, build-numbers

I want the compiled application to have the commit number, source files checksums and other things to be available during the compilation.

In plain Makefiles I do like this:

```
prog: VERSION source.c
    gcc -DVERSION=\"$(shell cat VERSION)\" source.c -o prog 

VERSION: .git
    git describe > VERSION
```

How to use something similar with qmake?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you were to pass the version information as an included file (let's say "version.h") instead of a #define, then you could add the following to your qmake file

```
# Define how to create version.h
version.target = version.h
version.commands = <PUT_YOUR_COMMANDS_HERE>
version.depends = .git

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += version

PRE_TARGETDEPS += version.h
```

The first 3 lines tell how to make a new target object called "version" that generates "version.h".  It is made by executing the commands "<PUT_YOUR_COMMANDS_HERE>".  The target is dependent on ".git"

The "QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS" says there is a new target known as "version".

The "PRE_TARGETDEPS" indicates that "version.h" needs to exist before anything else can be done (which forces it to be made if it isn't already made).

Comment: Trying to get this to work, having other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192714/how-to-refer-to-the-source-directory-in-qmake

Comment: Unfortunately `PRE_TARGETDEPS` only puts the target at the front of the dependency list of the final target. Thus as soon as you compile in parallel runing `make -j` this is likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution even if @jwernemy as nice way to solve it:

```
VERSION = $$system(-git-dir=$PWD/.git <PUT_YOUR_GIT_COMMANDS_HERE>)
```

Comment: In what directory will the command run? In source directory or in build directory?

Comment: And the `.git` is in the source directory.

Comment: you can use git `--git-dir` to specify the .git folder

Comment: like that `git --git-dir=$PWD/.git <YOU_COMMANDS_HERE`