# $$PWD no longer working in Qt Creator 2.6

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have a project (https://github.com/waddlesplash/qtfastjson) that has a .pri file that uses qmake's `$$PWD` variable. This works fine in all tested versions of qmake, but in Qt Creator 2.6, the files are not displayed in the project tree (but it compiles properly).

Here's the PRI:

```
QT += core
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD

HEADERS += $$PWD/QtFastJson.h \
    $$PWD/QtFastJsonObject.h

SOURCES += $$PWD/QtFastJson.cpp \
    $$PWD/QtFastJsonObject.cpp
```

which is included from a .pro: `include(../src/QtFastJson.pri)`.

If the `$$PWD` variables are removed and replaced with relative paths, the files show in the tree.

Comment: If you are doing a Shadow Build, then PWD may not be what you expect.  (See the replies to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192714/how-to-refer-to-the-source-directory-in-qmake/5195361#5195361) )

Comment: I do use Shadow Build, but this worked until QtCreator 2.6.... Perhaps because of the `../` in the `include()`? I think other PRIs with $$PWD in them work if the .pro does not use a ../ in the include, so is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me in Qt Creator 2.6. Try to place a log immediately before appending to the HEADERS variable:

```
message($$PWD)
```

Then check if that path really contains the files you're adding.
Also you can try with the _PRO_FILE_PWD_ variable.

Comment: It complies fine. Qt Creator just won't show the files in the tree, but it did pre-2.6. I'm starting to think this is really a bug about ../ in include().

Comment: Yes, I read your question already. Your comment is not useful however. What is the output of that message?

Comment: The message outputs the directory that the .pri file is in, which is where the source files are.