# Get the date with qmake

Tags: date, qmake

Since I'm using today's date for my application version, I'd be interested in filling it automatically.

Currently I'm doing the following in my project file:

```
VERSION = 15.4.20
```

But I'd like to make it automatic:

```
VERSION = $$YEAR.$$MONTH.$$DAY
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use undocumented `qmake` variable `_DATE_`, which is available on all platforms:

```
BUILD_YEAR = $$str_member($${_DATE_}, -4, -1)
message("Build year '$${BUILD_YEAR}' out of '$${_DATE_}'")
```

See [Undocumented QMake](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` with something like

```
$$version = date +%y.%m.%d
```

## Edit

On Mac OS you can use:

```
VERSION = $$system(date +%y.%m.%d)
```

Adapt it to fit your others supported OS ;)

Comment: this can not be a post link step since the version number is used during build.

Comment: but using the date command with the arg you gave is interesting!

Comment: @MartinDelille if you need more information about [a trick for prebuild step in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083441/how-to-add-pre-build-step-in-qmake-qtcreator)

Comment: On Windows,this could be `VERSION = $$system(date /t) $$system(time /t)`

Comment: @Andy.G On Windows this kind of not work. It works for the "product version", but not for the "file version". In the "file version" the date is taken as a math operation because of the `-` between the years, months and days values. It is the result of this math operation that is put inside the  "file version" field.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we just needed `year` for copyright:

```
company = My-Company
win32 {
    year = $$system("echo %date:~10,4%")
} else {
    year = $$system("date +%Y")
}
copyright = "Copyright (C) 2017-$$year, $$company"
```

Also, we used commit-hash decimal as version suffix:

```
win32 {
    commit = $$system("FOR /F \"tokens=*\" %H IN ('git rev-parse --short HEAD') DO @SET /A DECIMAL=0x%H")
} else {
    commit = $$system("printf '%d' 0x`git rev-parse --short HEAD`")
}
```