# Get datetime using qmake

Tags: c++, windows, qt, datetime, qmake

We can get [datetime using qmake](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake) `_DATE_` which outputs

```
Sat Mar 12 17:29:00 2022
```

Can we format this output?

Comment: You mean, the compilation date/time ?

Comment: Yes the compilation date/time

Comment: I'm using this syntax in my .PRO file :

(depending if you are in windows or not)

win32 {
DEFINES += BUILDTIME=\\\"$$system('echo %time%')\\\"
DEFINES += BUILDDATE=\\\"$$system('echo %date%')\\\"
} else {
DEFINES += BUILDTIME=\\\"$$system(date '+%H:%M.%s')\\\"
DEFINES += BUILDDATE=\\\"$$system(date '+%d/%m/%y')\\\"
}

then this in my code : 

QString::fromLocal8Bit(BUILDDATE)

By using QdateTime you may be able to convert the date (fromString() into what you want...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122206/echo-date-en-vs-cn?noredirect=1#comment127432911_72122206

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the date with qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753345/get-the-date-with-qmake)

Answer (score 0):

By using [QDateTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString) by passing the value of *DATE* (in fromString), you may be able to format the output the way you want, by using toString.

You can try things like this :

```
toString("ddd MMMM d  hh:mm:ss yy");  //Sat Mar 12 17:29:00 2022
```

Comment: I need it at qmake time, as specified on question title. Because I'll write files at qmake time using datetime on filename.

Comment: Aouch sorry, I got it. Check my first comment and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753345/get-the-date-with-qmake

Comment: Well I didn't got your point with the comment, compilation date/time is what I call qmake time, right?

Comment: Yes ! In my case, BUILDTIME and BUILDDATE variables are containing the date/time when I actually run qmake. But watch out, you can actually compile your code without calling qmake, and have a physical compilation datetime different from the qmake one !

Comment: Yes for the watch out case, not getting into it though. But it's explained in the question (comment below your comment) why that approach cannot be used, `%date%` depends on locate. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the location is a problem... There are solutions to format the output of %time% and %date% but it may hard to implement... See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format

Comment: `wmic os get LocalDateTime` seems interesting